# Are there publicly available ephemerides for any Moon-orbiting satellites?

Tags: the-moon, reference-request

I am currently working on expanding an orbital propagator to cover satellites that do not orbit Earth. For starters, I am trying to expand it to Moon-orbiting satellites. I have managed to reconstruct the Moon gravitational field from the GRGM1200L model, and converted the resulting accelerations from Moon Principal Axes frame into ICRF.

In order to test if my implementation is accurate, I would like to propagate the position of a Moon-orbiting satellite using the gravity field resulting from using Stokes' coefficients of different degrees. If the implementation is correct, the error should become smaller as I increase the maximum degree of the employed Stokes' coefficients.

However, in order to do so, I would need some trustable ephemerides of a Moon orbiting satellite to compare to.

So my question is, are there any ephemerides for any Moon-orbiting satellite publicly available?

Comment: I'd recommend the [pair of GRAIL satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRAIL), but it would be an interesting case since the gravity model you're using [was *derived from* their orbit](https://pgda.gsfc.nasa.gov/products/80). You can get their tracking data online somewhere ([this](https://pds.nasa.gov/ds-view/pds/viewDataset.jsp?dsid=GRAIL-L-RSS-2-EDR-V1.0) is probably too raw though) Instead you can look for the JPL ephemeris for GRAIL (A or B) or LRO in [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/). Those are synthesized trajectories but should be good for gross verification.

Comment: They may not match your model to one meter nor one millisecond, but maybe... better than a kilometer? I'm just guessing at that.

Comment: This is really *excellent*, thanks a lot! I will update with results [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19566/how-to-make-a-python-function-return-the-moons-gravitational-force-acceleratio), in case they are useful!